# How to create an editable and resizeable text field in svg document using batik api?

Tags: svg, batik

I can create text element in svg document using following code.

```
Element textElement = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "x", Integer.valueOf(end.x).toString());
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "y", Integer.valueOf(end.y).toString());
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", anycolor);
textElement.setAttributeNS(null, "font-size", String.valueOf(TEXT_FONT_SIZE));
textElement.setTextContent(text);
```

This element is not editable or resizable. Can someone help me to make this work same as the text tool in paint?

Answer (score 1):

To make it resizable, you could wrap it in a group and apply a transform on the group with a scale. For editable, you'll have to do something more complex.